# How can I see the colored log using tail or less?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, less, tail, ansi-escape

[image]

Reading a `Rails` log with `vim`, we can see a colored log.
But when we use `tail -f` or `less` to watch the log, it isn't colorized anymore. Is there any way to see the colored log with `tail` or `less` or whatever?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output

Comment: `grc` is exactry what I wanted. thank you so much.

Answer (score 21):

pass `-R` to less for it to let colour escape sequences pass through, i.e.

```
less -R log/development.log
```

This should result in them being displayed in colour, assuming you are using the proper terminal type

Comment: Could you explain about the *proper terminal type* little more?

Comment: The colours come from unprintable characters that tell your terminal to switch colours. If your terminal isn't configured to display colours this will do nothing. How you set this up is platform dependant - on OS x's standard terminal  it's the ANSI colors setting.

Answer (score 7):

```
tail -f log/development.log | ccze -A
```

You may need to install ccze

```
sudo apt-get install ccze
```

it works better, not ideal but works

Comment: On Mac OSX use ```brew install ccze```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that out of the box, since tail and less know nothing about Rails, and logs are saved a simple text files. You could use regular expressions to colorize output but I doubt it's worth the trouble.

EDIT: see alfonso's comment for some alternatives.

Comment: You are right. It was a simple text file. Though, how can it be seen colorized in vim? The file extension was just `.log` Nothing special.

Comment: Because vim does have syntax highlighting built in.